# Scale MapOvleray in WindowsPhone8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, zooming, here-api

i want to scale the mapoverlay content as the map is zoomed in or out.
Map Zoom is controlled by the ZoomLevel of the Map.
Does anybody know a formula that scales the image in the MapOverlay the same amount as the map?

I am looking for something like

```
public void OnZoomLevelChanged()
{
    img.Width = initialWidth * Map.ZoomLevel * [someRatioFactor]
    img.Height= initialHeight * Map.ZoomLevel * [someRatioFactor]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here for details on scaling/zoom level

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa940990.aspx

If you need to scale to the correct distance per pixel each time you zoom in/out, you can use something like the following function:

```
public static double MetersToPixels(double meters, double latitude, double zoomLevel)
    {
        var pixels = meters / (156543.04 * Math.Cos(latitude) / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel)));
        return Math.Abs(pixels);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone applying the solution of snacky in a real world szenario:

```
Math.Cos(double)
```

expects a radian angle. If you get the latitude from lets say

```
Geopoint.Latitude
```

which is in degrees you need to correct it like this:

```
public static double MetersToPixels(double meters, double latitude, double zoomLevel)
{
    var pixels = meters / (156543.04 * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * latitude) / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel)));
    return Math.Abs(pixels);
}
```

Hope this doesn´t belong to the comments or should I have edited snackys post?